# sql query wont work because of '

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to find all instances in a database where there is a ' in the name.. Like Jason's Store.

Problem is, the ' messes the query up

```
SELECT * 
FROM `paydayloan` 
WHERE `company` LIKE '%'%'
```

The ' in the middle ends the string, How do I get around this?

Comment: Use PDO or mysqli, and a prepared statement with bound variables.

Comment: Use double quotes `Like "%'%"`

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use double quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM paydayloan WHERE company LIKE "%'%";
```

Answer (score 2):

Using MySQLi or PDO prepared statements, this wouldn't be an issue.

Otherwise you need to escape your values.

Answer (score 1):

You could escape the quote like this:

```
SELECT * FROM paydayloan WHERE company LIKE '%''%'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use double quotes.

```
SELECT * FROM paydayloan WHERE company LIKE "%'%";
```